# Generated Java code (swagger) does not compile

Tags: java, enums, swagger, extends

I'm trying to create e Java client defined with swagger. I have generated the source code automatically in three ways.

- online https://editor.swagger.io/
- java -jar swagger-codegen-cli-3.0.20.jar generate -i https://www.xxxxxx.xxx/xxxxxx/swagger.json -l java
- swagger-codegen generate -i https://www.xxxxxx.xxx/xxxxxx/swagger.json -l java

Unfortunately, the generated source code cannot be compiled in all ways.
When I execute

mvn clean install

I get many errors of this type:

A.java cannot inherit from final B

I have analyzed the error and found the following pattern many times.

```java
public class A extends B {
    ....
}
```

```java
public enum B {
    ....
}
```

I know that the swagger provider works with c# and in this language this construct should be allowed.

I see the following in jason

```jason
"xxxx.xxxx.xx.B": {
        "enum": [
          "A",
          "B",
          "C",
          "D"
        ],
        "type": "string"
      }

...

"b": {
    "allOf": [
        {
        "$ref": "#/xxxx/xxxx/xxxx.xxxx.xx.B"
        }
    ],
    "description": "abc",
    "nullable": true
    }
```

I am not allowed to publish the swagger URL.

Is there anything I can do to build a Java client anyway?

Comment: That's not valid Java code - you can't inherit from an `enum`.  Your code must change.

Comment: you can implement any interface in enum 
look this might be useful:
https://www.programiz.com/java-programming/enum-inheritance#:~:text=Inheriting%20an%20enum%20Class%20from,lang.

Comment: I think there's something wrong with your code generator.You can't inherit from enums in java.Think about Enum like a final class with static final instances of itself.You cannot extend a final class.